# How to run Aurora-MySQL time consuming store procedure serverless beyond the 300 second limit

Tags: serverless, amazon-aurora

We are running stored procedures on AWS Aurora-MySQL from AWS Lambda.
Some stored procedures take more than 300 seconds so Lambda is not useful to wait and keep the connection alive to MySQL until process is done.

Any other way to serverless run a routine on Aurora without the time restriction?

Answer (score 1):

If a stored procedure takes more than 300 seconds I'd look into

1) Optimizing the stored procedure itself

2) Redesign with asynchronous processing principles using SQS or similar messaging service and also look into [Aurora calling Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html) once the stored procedure is executed.

Comment: Already done number (1) but there are routines that perform large calculations (inventory replenishment and purchase order suggestions) that may take 30 minutes or more. At present time we are thinking on using MySQL Event Scheduler and launch it from CloudWatch Events. I'll keep posted on this.